# how to call Joomla component method by variable?

Tags: php, variables, methods, joomla, call

```
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('NameOfModel', $prefix = 'my_componentModel', $config = array());
```

Normally, I would call the models method like this:

```
$this->items = $model->my_method();
```

In my case, I need to call the method by variable, because it is dynamic:

```
$this->items = $model->$variable; ...but this won't work.
$this->items = $model->{$variable}; ...this also won't work.
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code sample is right, the most likely answer is that you mean to call a method whose name is `$variable`, but you've [forgotten the `()` at the end](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php#example-182). i.e. your calling line should read:

```php
$this->items = $model->$variable();
```

If, that's not a typo and you did mean to call a [`property` of the class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), it's likely that the contents of `$variable` don't have a matching property/method in `$model`.

When using variable `properpty` or `method` names you will better off wrapping your calls in a simple check the [existence of the property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) or [method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php), to catch the problem before hand. e.g.

```php
// Check $model has a method $variable
if (method_exists($model, $variable)
{
    $this->items = $model->$variable();
}
else
{
    ... raise a error/warning message here ...
}

// Check $model has a property $variable
if (property_exists($model, $variable)
{
    $this->items = $model->$variable;
}
else
{
    ... raise a error/warning message here ...
}
```

Comment: you are right! I've forgotten the round brackets! Thank you!